# Why Kivy is not refreshing/updating my screen when I need it?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am having this problem:

A screen was created to show the messages that comes during an synchronization event that may last one minute, for example. More or less every two seconds one message will come.

I was expexting that when a message was received that message would be immediately printed.

But what happens with this code is that all the messages are printed at once when the whole syncronizarion ends, and not when each message comes, as expected.

.py:

```
class SyncScreen(Screen):
    content = StringProperty()

    def on_enter(self):
        self.content = "Synchronization messages"
        controller.synchronize(self.update_text)

    def update_text(self, msg):    # Callback
        self.content = self.content + msg
```

.kv:

```
<SyncScreen>:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDToolbar:
            title: "Synchronization"
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: 10
            TextInput:
                text: root.content
                size_hint: 1.0, 1.0
                multiline: True
```

Comment: maybe try to add a loop with clock.scedule_intervall()

Comment: I believe now that controller.synchronize(callback) is a "long" running function that keeps the program control out of Kivy main loop for a minute or so, and due to this, the screen is not redrawn during this time. But I still don't know how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `synchronize` function is blocking, Kivy can't draw anything until it returns. Run it in a thread, or do something like have it return (and get re-scheduled) every frame.

Comment: It worked. Thank you, @inclement
###
import threading ###
thread = threading.Thread(target=controller.synchronize, args=(self.update_text,)) ###
thread.start()
###
I just stumbled in another error. SQLite3 (used in synchronize() and other parts of my code) does not like being used in different threads with a single connection. But that's another issue.